# T-SQL Query for Max Date less 1 (without view or temp table)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I currently have a T-SQL query that pulls a list of historical invoice dates and snags the 2nd to last invoice date with use of a temp table.  The thing is, I need to use this query in a pre-processor in a 3rd party application that does not work well with the use of creating and dropping temp tables.  Is there a way to write the following T-SQL query without use of a View or Temp Table?

```
SELECT (convert(CHAR(10), dateadd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, ltradat), 0), 126)) AS 'DateOnly'
INTO #temp
FROM matter WITH (NOLOCK)
    ,ledger WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE mclient = '014134'
    AND lmatter = mmatter
    AND lzero != 'R'
    AND mcurrency LIKE '%'
    AND llcode != 'PAY'
GROUP BY ltradat
ORDER BY ltradat

SELECT max(DateOnly)
FROM #temp
WHERE DateOnly < (
        SELECT max(DateOnly)
        FROM #Temp
        )

DROP TABLE #temp
```

The #Temp table gives a list of invoice dates and matters tied to those invoices.  The select gives a single invoice date less 1 from the list (sorted earliest to most current).

If I select * from #Temp, I get a list like:

```
2016-06-08
2016-07-12
2016-07-26
2016-08-05
2016-09-12
```

When I run the final part of the T-SQL query, I get the result that I require of:

```
2016-08-05
```

Is it possible to get this result from a single query with no TEMP table or VIEW?

Thank you in advance.

-Nick

Comment: Table variable? CTE? Create a staging table that you truncate at the beginning/end of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use sub-query instead of temp tables or views to get the 2nd most recent date? Like

```
  SELECT MAX(DateOnly) 
  FROM (
            SELECT TOP 2 (convert(CHAR(10), dateadd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, ltradat), 0), 126)) AS DateOnly
            FROM matter WITH (NOLOCK)
                ,ledger WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE mclient = '014134'
                AND lmatter = mmatter
                AND lzero != 'R'
                AND mcurrency LIKE '%'
                AND llcode != 'PAY'
            GROUP BY ltradat
            ORDER BY ltradat
       ) AS b
```

Comment: This worked for me once I changed the order to 
ORDER BY ltradat DESC